# realexpayment(payment system) test account causes error

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, realex-payments-api

While processing payment in realexpayment system, I am getting following error :

```
320
An error has occurred processing your request. Please contact the merchant whose goods or services you are purchasing quoting the following error number: 61335
```

do anyone know what it could be?

I am posting parameters like this

```
<form method="POST" action="https://hpp.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay">
<input type="hidden" name="TIMESTAMP" value="timestampvalue">
<input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" value="mymerchantid">
<input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" value="orderid">
<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="amount">
<input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="currency(GBP)">
<input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" value="hashvalue">
<input type="hidden" name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Click To Pay">
</form>
```

hashvalue I am making by this algorithm: `sha1(sha1(timestamp.merchantid.orderid.amount.currency).secretkey)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your query and apologies for the late reply. A 320 should only occur if there is a temporary issue with our Sandbox environment. The POST you are sending is fine, but the environment just wasn't available at the particular moment.

Best,

Seán MacDomhnall

**Realex Payments**

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error id with the error below

```
*Error:320
Message: An error occurred processing your transaction. Please return to the merchant's  website and try again.*
```

We had to use 3d secure test card number to avoid this error.

We contacted Realex support to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hello Prageeth, welcome to SO! I think your answer could have been more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.

Comment: @Koresh I remember that for next time :)